# "We can able to" or "we are able to"

Tags: tenses, modal-verbs, future, can-vs-be-able

Can someone tell me if "we can able to" or "we are able to" is the correct usage? I feel the latter is correct. However, I noticed the former usage in a few write ups and emails.

Comment: *CAN ABLE TO* is ungrammatical and redundant!

Comment: I am from India and I still have to encounter any English student who was taught or is using *can able to*. It is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"we are able to do it" is right because able is adjective.
"we can" shouldn't go with "able" because "can" is a losing auxiliary so it must support a verb,so "we can be able to do it" is correct.